# how to configure the menus in section content with Prestashop

Tags: layout, menu, prestashop

I am building a website with Prestashop and I like how the homepage and the rest of the pages look like but the static pages look different and I would like to be able to keep the same layout with the vertical menus/modules in the left column

Check it out http://reconnectedit.com/dev/ and check about us for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In backoffice you have a menu `Preferences -> Themes`.

Click on `Advanced settings` button and scroll down the list to find `cms` and click the red x on the `Left column` column to enable the display of modules on left side in CMS pages.